# Eagerly load recursive relation

Tags: nhibernate

I have a recursive one-to-many relationship that has the default lazy value of true. What code can I write against the NH API that will efficiently retrieve the ENTIRE tree AS IF I had lazy="false" on the SubCategories mapping?

Here's the recursive one-to-many relationship:

```
<class name="Category" lazy="false">
    ...
    <list name="SubCategories" fetch="subselect">
            <key column="ParentCategoryID"/>
            <index column="PositionInList"/>
            <one-to-many class="Category"/>
    </list>
```

I don't specify lazy="false" on the list since laziness is required in about half the queries I need to run.  I have fetch="subselect" on the list as an optimization for when I do manage to retrieve the entire tree.

I've tried the ICriteria API:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Category>().SetFetchMode( "SubCategories", FetchMode.Eager ).Add( Restrictions.IsNull("ParentCategory") ).SetResultTransformer( CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity ).List<Category>();
```

but that only eagerly loaded only the first level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Ayende's site: [Efficiently Selecting a Tree](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx).  I have successfully used this technique in my own applications.  With ICriteria, it looks like this:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Category>()
    .SetFetchMode("SubCategories", FetchMode.Join)
    .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .List<Category>()
    .Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null);
```

The main difference between this version and what you tried is how the "ParentCategory == null" filter is applied.  It has to be left out of the query that is sent to the database in order to retrieve the whole tree - but we still need the query to only return the root nodes of the tree, so we'll use linq to find those after the database query has completed.

Answer (score 1):

I used Daniel's code as a bases for solving the problem.  I also experimented with the equivalent HQL that I shared below.  The HQL executed slightly faster, but I went with ICriteria since I could then choose between FetchModel.Join and FetchModel.Lazy.

```
session.CreateQuery( "from Category as c left join fetch c.SubCategories" )
  .SetResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() )
  .List<Category>()
  .Where( c => c.ParentCategory == null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but take a look at : [map a tree in NHibernate](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate)

Comment: Yes, that's a useful article and I've already read it.  When I was investigating fast loading of trees several months ago, I found the "Eager load ancestors and descendants" section relevant.  My database is SQL Compact, however, and does not support CTEs (hierarchical queries).  So writing a single query that solves the problem looks impossible.