# What is the best way to do a recursive SQL query on a self join field (as well as doing it through nhibernate?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, recursive-query

I have a database table called **Employee** and it the following columns:

- Id
- Name
- ManagerId

The column called **ManagerId** is a self join field in the same table (as a manager is just another employee.

I now want to run a query that :

Take in a parameter of Id (taking a single manager) and want to get all of the people that roll up into that person.  So if I do

```
 Select * from ManagerId = 1
```

I will only get the direct reports of that manager and i want to get EVERYONE that rolls up to that manager recursively.

- The direct reports
- The direct reports of the direct reports
- The direct reports of the direct reports of the direct reports
- etc . . .

Also, I am using fluent nhibernate in my solution so also would like to get some suggestions there as well.  If i do this in a loop in code it seems like it will running many queries if a manager has a number of layers of people under them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eagerly load recursive relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223163/eagerly-load-recursive-relation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE, you can build the hierarchy.  Filtering the top level query by your search criteria, you can get the results you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = 3;

WITH    Emp
          AS (SELECT    te.id
                      , te.Name
                      , te.ManagerId
                      , CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ManagerName
              FROM      dbo.tblEmployee AS te
              -- Get entire heirarchy with the NULL ManagerId
              --WHERE     ManagerId IS NULL
              WHERE     te.id = @id
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    te2.id
                      , te2.Name
                      , e.id
                      , e.Name
              FROM      dbo.tblEmployee AS te2
              JOIN      Emp e
                        ON e.id = te2.ManagerId
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Emp;
```

UPDATE:
For your comment about not including the record for the `id` passed, you can do two things:

The easiest way would be to add a where clause to the last select:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Emp
WHERE emp.ID <> @id;
```

Alternatively, if you didn't need the `ManagerName` field to be populated for the top level of the hierarchy, you can what the first where clause in the CTE:

```
SELECT    te.id
, te.Name
, te.ManagerId
, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ManagerName
FROM      dbo.tblEmployee AS te
-- Get entire heirarchy with the NULL ManagerId
--WHERE     ManagerId IS NULL
--WHERE     te.id = @id
WHERE ManagerId = @id
```

Comment: it looks like the id passed as the parameter is included in the results sets.  Is there anyway to not include it?  Let me know and i will accpe this answer